# SQL Group By of Date not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have this SQL code:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) AS StatMonth, timestamp
  FROM server_stats
 GROUP BY StatMonth
 ORDER BY StatMonth DESC;
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `players_online` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `active_players` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_copper` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_items` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_item_weight` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_houses` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_boats` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_pets` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_experience` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=63 ;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `server_stats` (`id`, `timestamp`, `players_online`, `active_players`,
        `total_copper`, `total_items`, `total_item_weight`, `total_houses`,
        `total_boats`, `total_pets`, `total_experience`) VALUES
(53, 1317288600, 227, 718, 155037828, 68231283, 25169498, 14822, 2112, 683, 7776385802),
(54, 1317290400, 224, 718, 155038479, 68233576, 25163526, 14822, 2112, 683, 7776669410),
(55, 1317292200, 215, 718, 155100860, 68239613, 25160397, 14822, 2112, 683, 7776933725),
(56, 1317294000, 201, 717, 155095895, 68240842, 25159809, 14822, 2112, 683, 7777196134),
(57, 1317295800, 204, 718, 155090280, 68248539, 25170275, 14822, 2112, 683, 7777419238),
(58, 1317297600, 194, 718, 155105906, 68259213, 25163212, 14823, 2112, 683, 7777657681),
(59, 1317682800, 230, 724, 157323143, 68731571, 25185326, 14908, 2119, 692, 7834358253),
(60, 1317684600, 213, 724, 157323178, 68733325, 25186412, 14908, 2119, 692, 7834637558),
(61, 1317686400, 219, 724, 157314147, 68737824, 25197057, 14908, 2119, 692, 7834904982),
(62, 1317688200, 225, 725, 157329100, 68736384, 25190554, 14909, 2119, 692, 7835169244);
```

I am using the SELECT statement above to display each month. Which in this case should be September (9) and October (10). However, it is only displaying September, not October.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This works fine in MySQL 5.1, provided you use `MONTH FROM from_unixtime(timestamp)`. Which SQL server are you using?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but How about using DATE() instead of int for the date?

Comment: mySQL 5.1.56. And "imm" your code there solved it! I appreciate it! :D

Comment: @imm : Please post your comment as an answer so this question can be completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine in MySQL 5.1, provided you use `MONTH FROM from_unixtime(timestamp)`.